# How should I push and pull data from a server using REST API and Later generate reports from it

Tags: database, rest, powerbi, cloud

I am new to REST API. What I basically understand from REST API is you need to call it each time to get the updated data.
In my case, I need to use the data received from REST API to generate reports in PowerBI. Adding on, I should be able to "read" the data coming from the server and "write" to the data as well.
I did find the option of getting data from WEB in PowerBI to connect directly to REST API. So, if I do that I can only "read".
Can you help me with different options on how can I do both "read/pull" and "write/push" to the server when I have its REST API? I am not sure if a cloud has to be used in-between.

Comment: Hi Treesa George. In API terms, to 'read' is called a GET request, and to 'write' is called a POST request. Not familiar with PowerBI - it seems to be a reporting/charting tool. A REST API is a service which allows you to GET information and use it somewhere else (such as your PowerBI tool), but it often requires special permissions to use. Even if you don't need permission to GET data, you will often need permission if you want to update or POST data back to the API. You would normally have to send a username, password and perhaps more.  Have you permission to use the API?

Comment: Would be good to know if you are looking for help with APIs in general or with the PowerBI app